# How can i get contract data from certain block

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, python

I need to get some data from an smart contract, but i want to generate something like history

How can i get that data until some block or maybe be able to replay the blocks somehow?
Im using python and if there is a way with Web3 ot Geth that will be fantastic

Comment: you need to connect to an archive node, in web3js you can give an optional parameter for block number, I think it is also possible in python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On chain a contract can only query the latest state. A contract can store the information it needs in a mapping and consult from there, but the storage isn't automatic it has to be done explicitly.

Off chain commands like [`web3.eth.call`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0/web3-eth.html#call) and [`methods.myMethod.call`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call) accepts an extra parameter which indicates the block number to make the query from. The default parameter is "latest" which means the most recent block, but it can be used to specify a block number. A query to old blocks it might require an archive node.